# How to display ImageView in fullscreen?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, fullscreen

I want to display a image ,which is displayed in an ImageView, in fullscreensize if the user touches a button or the image itself. Is there a way to do this? I've seen similar on Facebook application. I want to display the image size the screen in portrait mode and when the orientation was changed in landscape mode I want that the image fits the screen. Is there a way to do this maybe a sample code? And how can the user exit the fullscreen mode? Maybe this is possible with a subvie, but I dont know how to treat that.

Here is what I mean:

Portrait mode:

[image]

Landscape mode:
[image]

And the close Button. The comment section is not needed.
[image]

I would be happy if someone could help me with this.

Best regards.

Comment: How is your project setup? With XIBs, Storyboards, Programmatically?

Comment: I'm using iPhone Storyboard and my default orientation is portrait

Comment: Look into autoresizingmasks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description you gave it is similar to the photo gallery app in the iOS, which has zoom scroll and many more functions.

Check out this open source [sample](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser).

Created by Michael Waterfall, which includes photo gallery from images stored on server or locally.

You can modify the code as per your project requirements. And it is easy to handle the images.
This will suit your need.

**Edit**: 
You can handle the classes in this way, you can see in the sample code it has 2 classes `MWPhotoBrowser` which is a photo browser a viewController. And a `MWPhoto` used to represent the photo objects.

You need to maintain photos list in `MWPhoto` formats only, so while using you can have a tableView showing all the photos in thumbnail in grid view style and on tapping any image your code should open that image in `MWPhotoBrowser` means your photos array will be same same just start index you need to change.

Comment: I'm gonna take a look. Thanks for response.

Comment: do you know how to handle those files? theres no example

Comment: I've set up all correctly and I wanted to show the navController but if I tap the button to display the navController (the button is on a popup view) the controller appers behind the popup! Can I make it that it shows me above of all views? Here is my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13773682/subview-displays-wrong aaaand here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777395/display-navigationcontroller-on-top Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NoahRaissi has ur issue fixed..? is it possible to giv the sample code on which u r working..?

Comment: Well as you can see above I wrote that the controller alsways diplay in my folder and not on top on all views so I cant actually see the picture. Take a look at the questions and please say me what I'm doing wrong. Both questions are mine so you can choose which one you like to awnser. I would happy if you could say me a solution to but the navcontroller on above the popover. And it works actually I can see that it appears but it appears in my folder which I dont want to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pod XLMediaZoom to show images and videos in fullscreen like Instagram. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282163/1070393