# Subview displays wrong

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, subview

I've made a project and implemented the [folder project](https://github.com/jwilling/JWFolders) and now I've set up a subview which is displayed aboce the folder like on the picture. On the popup there's a image and I would like to do it like this that if I tap the image a new controller with the whole image will displayed. I've set up all correctly...However, I tried to change the subview etc. THIS Navigationcontroller never appears at the top of all "layers". it appears in the folderviewcontroller. By the way, the Navcontroller is set up by this project: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser and the Popup was set up through this: https://github.com/kgn/KGModal

So here's my code:

```
-(IBAction)mehr:(id)sender {

    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 440)];
cubut = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                                                     [cubut addTarget:self
                                                               action:@selector(dothis:)
                                                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                                                     [cubut setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                                                     cubut.frame = CGRectMake(5, 70, 270, 200);

                                                     [contentView addSubview:cubut];
- (IBAction)dothis:(id)sender {

    MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

    // Set browser options.
    browser.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
    browser.displayActionButton = YES;


    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:browser];

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];





    NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MWPhoto *photo;
    photo = [MWPhoto photoWithFilePath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"star" ofType:@"png"]];
    photo.caption = @"The star is soo beateful...";
    [photos addObject:photo];

    self.photos = photos;






}
- (MWPhoto *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index < _photos.count)
        return [_photos objectAtIndex:index];
    return nil;
}
- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser {
    return _photos.count;
}
```

And the picture: 
(The button is set to custom so you cant see it...it has the same frame like the image)

[image]

Comment: This is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777395/display-navigationcontroller-on-top/13780689#13780689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was not finished so I have to awnser my own questions that I didnt found a solution for this.