# View Controller not presenting from App Delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am trying to load a viewController if there are no accounts logged in however it gives me this error `Warning: Attempt to present <DefaultViewController: 0xb96cac0> on <MainViewController: 0xb95c320> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`
 Here is the code that I am using right now:

```
BOOL returnAllOff = [[User data] returnAllOff];

if (returnAllOff) {
    DefaultViewController *viewController =[[DefaultViewController alloc]
    init];
    UIViewController *presentingController = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    [presentingController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13888062/whose-view-is-not-in-window-hierarchy-issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11862883/whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy

Comment: I tried the solution in the first link but i got the same issue

Comment: Where is that code? The error is quite clear about the reason.

Comment: Would i Have to add DefaultViewController in the mainviewcontroller class. FYI i am using storyboards.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is the correct way of loading a ViewController from AppDelegate..

```
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    DefaultViewController *viewController = [[DefaultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DefaultViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: It now gives this issue instead... `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Pradyumn/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/84A3CAF1-D22C-48E6-96D2-42F0CA9DF1E6/Floadt.app> (loaded)' with name 'DefaultViewController''`

Comment: you are using Storyboards?

Comment: I added that line now, however when the view loads its all black even though there are 2 buttons and the page is filled with color. @preetam

Answer (score 1):

Try this one by importing `DefaultViewController` in appDElegate.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
DefaultViewController *viewController = [[DefaultViewController alloc] init];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Comment: I added that line now, however when the view loads its all black even though there are 2 buttons and the page is filled with color.

Comment: which color you are giving to view?

Comment: its actually a ui image view

Comment: I think you are setting view background color to default color that clears everything on view

Comment: try taking a new view controller...first check it navigates or not then correspondingly make your required changes to that new view controller so that you can easily track where you were wrong?