# How to open image in full screen like facebook iphone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, imageview, fullscreen

I'm new in ios development and i want to open images in fullscreen mode like facebook iphone app , also I want the event which let you drag image to down and then open the image in fullscreen mode.
So anyone can help men ?

Comment: Welcome to SO - I encourage you to demonstrate some kind of effort or research on your part, people will be much more inclined to help. Also try to phrase the question really specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this pod: XLMediaZoom.
We recently developed it for our needs and shared here: [XLMediaZoom](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLMediaZoom)

If you use CocoaPods in your projects you just need to add

```
pod 'XLMediaZoom'
```

This utility let you preview images and videos in fullscreen like Instagram does.

Comment: But you cannot pinch zoom the image after it goes fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks @RemaR you saved my lots of time.. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To open image in full screen try this :

```
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
```

To let the user drag the image use [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference).

To look at examples of UIPanGestureRecognizer refer to [this](http://blog.shoguniphicus.com/2011/06/15/working-with-uigesturerecognizers-uipangesturerecognizer-uipinchgesturerecognizer/).